# Android date range picker allows unavailable dates in the range. How to prevent this?

Tags: android, date-range

I have a date ranger picker that includes a validator for unavailable days.  The validator works because I can see the unavailable dates greyed out.  However, the picker allows those dates to be included in the range. I would have thought this to be default behavior to not allow date ranges that include unavailable dates, but that's not the case.  How can I set the date picker to only allow date ranges that include only available dates?

```
val builder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.dateRangePicker()
   .setTheme(R.style.customMaterialCalendarDatePicker)
   .setCalendarConstraints(
     CalendarConstraints.Builder()
       .setStart(Date().time)
       .setEnd(oneYearFrom().time)
       .setValidator(AvailabilityValidator(state.unavailableDays)).build()
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution to your problem. You can use this DateValidatorPointForward and DateValidatorPointBackward to avoid dates that should not go in. Moreover, I have tried to refactor the code a bit.

```
// Define your min and max dates
val minDate = Date() // Today
val maxDate = oneYearFrom() // One year from today

// Create validators for min and max date
val dateValidatorMin = DateValidatorPointForward.from(minDate.time)
val dateValidatorMax = DateValidatorPointBackward.before(maxDate.time)

// Combine your validators into a list
val listValidators = mutableListOf<CalendarConstraints.DateValidator>()
listValidators.add(dateValidatorMin)
listValidators.add(dateValidatorMax)
listValidators.add(AvailabilityValidator(state.unavailableDays)) // your custom validator

// Combine all validators
val validators = CompositeDateValidator.allOf(listValidators)

val builder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.dateRangePicker()
    .setTheme(R.style.customMaterialCalendarDatePicker)
    .setCalendarConstraints(
        CalendarConstraints.Builder()
            .setStart(minDate.time)
            .setEnd(maxDate.time)
            .setValidator(validators).build()
    )
```